# Can a django (python) app be packaged to run on the desktop?

Tags: django, web-applications, desktop-application

I'm interested in Django for developing a new web app in Python. I'd like, though, to be able to re-use the same code in a desktop python app. (This is one of the attractions of Python for me over PHP). Is there any established way to re-package an app written with Django as a desktop app?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can! But the only Django part that would be useful for a desktop app i can think of is the ORM. For the presentation layer you have to find a way to use HTML, or use python gwk (or something like that)

Comment: Could it somehow use the Django framework to run in a browser from the local machine? What I want to avoid is making the user set up a full server.

Comment: No problem, you can even make an .exe :)

Comment: Of course it can. The development server (the thing you run with 'runserver') can do this. The user just has to go to localhost:8000 by default and there's the app. If you use SQLite then you don't need a database server either.

Comment: OK, what I'm looking for is something that ordinary users could deploy quickly, like the .exe that Willian mentions. How would I go about producing an executable for Windows (or Linux, or OSX)? Is it possible to use mySQL or Postgresql

Comment: Mysql and Postgres must be installed on the client computer (or create a connection to a db server). Sqlite is far easier to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

There is [DjangoKit](http://code.google.com/p/djangokit/), which does what you want and creates a Mac GUI application based on a django project.

It might be simpler there because it's really easy to get a WebKit view to render HTML, but you may be able to use some ideas from it.

Comment: Is there anything equivalent for Windows or Linux?